# need to pass password to ansible-playbook command in GitLab pipeline

Tags: ansible, gitlab

I want to use a GitLab pipeline to run Ansible code on an on-prem server. I need to be able to SSH into the server using a username and password. I would like to store the username and password on a per host basis because it may change depending on the host. I can't figure out how to securely store the password and have the GitLab pipeline access it.
I would like to do something like this in my inventory file:

```
all:
    children:
        devices:
            children:
                standalone:
                    hosts:
                        vars:
                            ansible_user: nextgen
                        demo102:
                            ansible_host: **.**.***.***
                            ansible_ssh_pass: [point to encrypted password file]
```

I was able to encrypt a password file using the `ansible-vault` command. I can't figure how to point to the encrypted password file in my inventory or if it's even possible. As an alternative I looked into using the password file in the `ansible-playbook` command in the GitLab pipeline YAML. I tried passing the password file as a parameter but got an error of `A vault password must be specified to decrypt data...` I thought the `ansible-playbook` command would automatically decrypt the file and there's no option to supply the vault password.

Here's my GitLab YAML:

```
---
device-setup:
  image: 
    name: [custom Docker image with Ansible installed]
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: validation
  
  before_script:
    - ansible --version
  
  script:
    - ansible-playbook --vault-password-file inventory/host_vars/vault_pass.txt -i $HOST_NAME hostname_validation.yml
```

How do I get this to work? The Ansible documentation doesn't really cover this type of use case.